# On a Windows Mobile device, does it make sense to cache data "in memory"?

Tags: language-agnostic, memory, windows-mobile, caching, mobile

I'm writing a Windows CE application, and I want to play a sound (a short wav file) when something happens. Since this sound will be played often, my first instinct was to load the wav file into a memory stream and reuse that stream instead of reading the file every time.

But then it occured to me that these Windows Mobile devices only have *one* kind of memory, which is used *both* for data storage (= the file system) as well as for program memory; there's even a nice slider in the control panel which you can use to delegate memory to either storage or program execution. So, theoretically, reading a file from the file system (or some value from a SQL Server CE database) should take (almost) the same amount of time as reading this value from some in-memory object, right?

Is this assumption correct (i.e., in-memory caching on application level doesn't make sense here) or did I miss something? For simplicity, let's assume that only the internal memory of the device is used (no memory card).

Answer (score 1):

The assumption may or may not be valid.  Where in storage does it reside?  If it's persistent storage (like a storage card folder or anything else that remains when you hard reset) then it's backed by Flash, which is way, way slower than RAM and there will be a difference in load perf, though how much it might impact your app I can't say - only testing will tell you that.

Answer (score 1):

When I want to play a short WAV file on Windows Mobile (e.g. notification sound). I usually add it as a resource to my executable. AFAIK resources are loaded into RAM since they are part of the executable image. You can then conveniently call [PlaySound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms932262.aspx)() with the SND_RESOURCE (and probably OR that with SND_ASYNC too so the call isn't going to block while the file is being played) flag.